# Why this doesn't contradict Monotone and Dominated Convergence Theorem?

Tags: integration, measure-theory, lebesgue-integral

$$\lim_{n \to \infty} \int_0^\infty f_n(x)dx \ne \int_0^\infty \lim_{n \to \infty} f_n(x)dx$$

where : $f_n=ne^{-nx}$ for all $x \in [0,\infty)$ $n \in \mathbb{N}$

Can somebody help me with explanation?

Comment: Well, I suppose the $f_n$ are neither monotone nor dominated.

Comment: The MCT and the DCT allow you to exchange limits and integration provided your sequence of functions satisfy certain conditions. In the case of the MCT, your $(f_n)$ need to be a monotone increasing sequence, and need to converge pointwise to some $f(x)$ (they also need to be measurable, but if they aren't then a lot of what you wrote doesn't even make sense). In the case of the DCT, your sequence of functions doesn't need to be monotone increasing, but need to be dominated by an integrable function independent of $n$.

Answer (score 4):

Note that $e^{-nx} \geq 1-nx$. Therefore if $x \in \left [0,\frac{1}{2n} \right ]$, $f_n(x) \geq n/2$, so $\int_0^{\frac{1}{2n}} |f_n(x)| dx \geq 1/4$. Since $\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{1}{2n} = 0$, we conclude that $f_n$ is not uniformly integrable. Any dominated sequence is uniformly integrable, so your sequence is not dominated either. It's also easy to see that it is not monotone.

Answer (score 2):

The sequence $\{f_n\}$ is not increasing, so that discards MCT.

For DCT, I cannot find an easy argument that any function $g$ with $g\geq f_n$ for all $n$ cannot be integrable. But it has to be the case, because otherwise DCT would give equality.